# Run gradle commands from other directory

Tags: java, gradle

I have folder "A" and folder "B"
Folder "B" is having gradle code
I want to run `gradle clean` and `gradle build` command from folder "A" of folder "B"
How do I do this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You don't know how to start a program stored in another directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the "start directory" parameter (`-p, --project-dir`  :  see [Environment options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options))

I think the other available parameter `-b --build-file` could work as well, but its main usage is when your build script filename differs from default `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-b` parameter(i.e. `--build-file`)

```
cd A
gradle -b ../B/build.gradle
```

Answer (score 1):

for me this works

```
gradle clean build --console=plain -p ${projectPath}
```

Where:
clean: Is to "clean" build/libs folder.
Console plain: To show only build results in console

```
// Compilando
sh(label: 'Compilando', script: "gradle clean build --console=plain -p ${rutaTemp}")
sh(label: 'Listando archivos', script: "ls -lart ${rutaTemp}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is harder than it looks.
Dispite setting different values for --project-dir , --gradle-user-home , --build-file
No matter what you do, when you "println project.projectDir" from your build.gradle
script it will ALWAYS report back the directory in which "build.gradle" lives.

I wanted to re-arrange things in gradle because gradle pollutes your root directory
with a lot of junk! Uncle Bob of "Clean Code" (Robert C. Martin) would probably refer to this behavior as "rude code".

I finally figured it out after searching around all day.
Here is my project structure:

```
<root_folder>
 |
 +--[ .git       ]
 +--[ .gitignore ]
 |
 +--[-]src/main/java
 |   |
 |   +--Main.java
 |
 +--[-]RUN_ON_CMD
     |
     +--[-]Gradle
         +--[ build.gradle ]
         +--[ RUN.sh ]
         |
         +--[-]GENERATED
```

### .gitignore :

```
GENERATED/
```

---

### build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'                  
apply plugin: 'application'    

println "[project.projectDir]:"
println project.projectDir
mainClassName = 'Main'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            //:Because "build.gradle" lives in:
            //:<root>\RUN_ON_CMD\Gradle\GENERATED\
            srcDir '../../../src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

---

### RUN.sh

```
build_gradle=$( realpath build.gradle )
echo $build_gradle

current_directory=$( realpath "." )
echo $current_directory

generated=${current_directory}/"GENERATED"
echo $generated

cp $build_gradle $generated/"build.gradle"
gradle run -b $generated/"build.gradle" -g $generated --no-daemon
```

---

### main.java

```
public class 
Main{
    public static void 
    main( 
        String[] args
    ){

        System.out.println("[MAIN]");

    }
}
```

---

### To Run:

Do a "**git bash here**" inside the "**Gradle**" folder.
Then type:

> ./RUN.sh

And hit ENTER

---

### My output: (TDD_JAVA == root_folder )

```
JMIM@DESKTOP-JUDCNDL MINGW64 /c/DEV/REPO/GIT/TDD_JAVA/RUN_ON_CMD/Gradle (master)
$ ./RUN.sh
/c/DEV/REPO/GIT/TDD_JAVA/RUN_ON_CMD/Gradle/build.gradle
/c/DEV/REPO/GIT/TDD_JAVA
/c/DEV/REPO/GIT/TDD_JAVA/RUN_ON_CMD/Gradle
/c/DEV/REPO/GIT/TDD_JAVA/RUN_ON_CMD/Gradle/GENERATED
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

> Configure project :
[project.projectDir]:
C:\DEV\REPO\GIT\TDD_JAVA\RUN_ON_CMD\Gradle\GENERATED

> Task :run
[MAIN]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

---

All the junk generated by gradle is put into
the "**GENERATED**" folder. Then my .gitignore makes sure not to commit any of that junk.